# What's the asymptotically fastest known algorithm for computing the nullspace of a matrix?

Tags: matrix, theory

I know Gaussian Elimination and QR decomposition are both O(n^3).  Is there better?

I'm interested for theoretical reasons - I won't actually be coding this up, so approximations, or *sometimes* faster algorithms, are not useful.